# Since New York doesn't have a residential parking permit system, can a tourist park in Manhattan for free?

Tags: automobiles, new-york-city

It seems that neither New York in general nor Manhattan have any kind of residential parking system as of 2016. Does this mean that a tourist can just go and park a car in Manhattan free of charge?

I am aware that driving in central NYC is a bad idea but it's always nice to get free parking if possible.

Comment: If you can find a parking space without a meter....

Comment: @Roddy do the locals pay the meter all the time?

Comment: Locals pay the meters when the meters are in force. Some meters in Manhattan at least are only for commercial vehicles, though, so do be careful and read the signs.  But the basic principle is that there is no difference in parking enforcement based on the car's state of registration, and there's no way to know whether a New York car is from NYC or elsewhere. This is one of the main reasons why most Manhattanites don't have cars.

Comment: Anecdotally: Years ago I as a stupid tourist thought I'd read the signs correctly and found a legal park spot on the street in Manhattan. Wasn't impressed when I got back to find the car had been impounded within a few short hours. Just.... don't.

Comment: Park in Queens and take the subway.

Comment: You could make this question shorter by asking if a tourist in NYC can buy a winning lotto ticket.

Comment: Suggested reading on this topic -Tepper Isn't Going Out, by Calvin Trillin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes. Any tourist can park in the same areas as a resident.  The only "benefit" for residents of NYC is an exemption from paying the NYC 8% parking tax, though they still pay NY State portion of the tax of 10.375%.

In many areas of the city, largely south of E52nd street, almost all street parking is prohibited with exceptions made for Commercial vehicles (NY state license plate reads "commercial") and Handicap/Disabled parking.

Many parking garages offer coupons by visiting their site first, then downloading to your phone or printing. Icon Parking, Quik Park and LAZ Parking seem to own most garages. Sites like ParkWhiz can locate cheap parking for you, and often offer deals by directing traffic to specific garages.

All parking garages by law must post the rate clearly. It won't include the 18% sales tax. Be sure to know your car size, as they will charge extra for long, wide, tall, oversize, lifted, big tires, SUVs, etc.
Also, the rates are largely by-the-hour. Rates are lowest for people who arrive early (usually 7am - 10am) and stay over 8 hours and less than 12 hours. In that case, it will usually be a flat fee. I pay $27.00 (includes tax) to park in Midtown (busy area) from 7:00am - 6:45pm.

Some helpful notes, if you're serious about street parking:

- Look closely where a fire hydrant is located. You may not park within 15 feet of either side. You **will** be ticketed. The distance will not be marked.
- You may not park at the end of any street with either end of your car protruding into a crosswalk, unless the crosswalk is specifically not painted in the parking area as to allow room for a car. This is rare.
- Do not park too far away from the curb. You will get a ticket. Usually a 8" to 1ft max. Do not park with your tires on and touching the curb, you will be ticketed.
- It is possible to get a parking spot on the street. These can be found by waiting on a street until the street sweeper passes. As soon as they pass, drive into a spot behind the street sweeper and park. **Do not** leave your car, as you will still get a ticket. You must wait until the parking restriction time has elapsed, even though the street sweeper has already come. There can be fights that erupt, as residents wait in their cars idling on one side of the street and rush to the other side.
- [NYC DOT (Dept of Transportation) map with parking restrictions.](http://nycdot.info) Includes Alternative Side Parking (ASP) rules. Click "Parking Signs" as a map layer.
- ASP schedule is tweeted daily at 7:30am and 4:30pm ET by [Twitter account "NYCASP"](https://twitter.com/NYCASP).
- [The ASP calendar for 2016, 2017 and temporary suspensions.](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/html/motorist/alternate-side-parking.shtml)
- Manhattan residents are exempt from paying the additional New York City 8% Parking Tax. Manhattan residents instead pay only the tax on parking services at a rate of 10.375% instead of 18.375% that is imposed under State law.

Comment: 8% parking tax? Is this a tax on personal income or on parking fees where a meter is present?

Comment: @JonathanReez it's an additional 8% on the sales tax a parking tower charges you.

Comment: @JonathanReez it's 18.375% total counting all sources of tax (for those not exempt), and it's a tax on all paid parking *except* meters (because those go to NYCDOT in the first place). Meaning, if you go to a parking garage or parking lot and the listed price is $15 for a period of time, you will actually pay $17.76.

Comment: @hobbs in practice, though, the published pre-tax rates are calculated so the after-tax rate is a round number.

Comment: @phoog true enough.

Comment: Getting a spot on the street does not literally require following the street sweeper. I grew up in Manhattan, and never once did that. Street parking is a pain, but it’s entirely do-able in many areas of the city (and entirely impossible in others, particularly touristy sections, but I digress).

Comment: When I lived in Brooklyn a decade ago, everyone flipped sides of the street immediately after the street cleaner went by and immediately left their cars.  No-one I knew ever had a problem.  Your ticketage may vary.  Also, I'm told the rules about the 15' fire hydrant parking exclusion and bike lanes (or sidewalk extensions) are arcane.  Even after reading the web sites complaining about it I don't understand the rules.

Comment: @SethRobertson Switching sides immediately after a street sweeper is one way, and most effective if parking in the morning. Simply driving around waiting for someone to leave also works, though usually around the 3 - 4pm hour (when doormen and handymen leave or shift change) and 6pm - 8pm (when visitors come and go from apartments). 

The fire hydrant/crosswalk rules are strictly enforced, speaking from personal experience parking in the East 60s and East 80s streets. I got a crosswalk ticket last month, 6 minutes after parking and was less than 1 ft within the crosswalk.

Comment: For 27 USD I can rent a private single garage in most German cities for a month.

Comment: @simbabque failing to see how that is in any way relevant?

Comment: @Mark I was just wondering if that is cheap or expensive. For non-US residents it's very hard to judge the value of parking. I know that for example some restaurants in San Francisco charge something like 20 dollars for parking plus a tip of almost the same amount for the valet. On the other hand parking lots might charge 10 dollars per hour. But I have no idea if that is a lot to locals. To me as a German it's a huge amount. Paying more for parking than for the meal I'm having while leaving the car outside is horrendous. I flinch at a garage that charges 2 Euros per hour. So is this a lot?

Comment: @simbabque yes, it is high (sometimes way higher) even if you compare to most, if not all cities in the US. But we are talking about NYC here. See [this](http://public.tableau.com/shared/JQFB29FXP?:display_count=yes) for a comparison

Comment: @simbabque I'm sure I can also find restaurants in in Germany that charges obscene amounts for valet parking. That said, yes - parking in NYC is extraordinarily expensive. I originally come from Sydney, Australia, which has outrageous parking costs in the inner city but NYC takes the cake. Maybe the most expensive in the entire world? Maybe London is more.

Comment: @simbabque It's expensive for most parts of the U.S., but SF and NYC are two of the most densely-populated places in the U.S. and their land is accordingly very expensive, thus parking is expensive. Those of us who live outside of the major city centers in the U.S. typically don't pay anything at all for parking. For comparison, Berlin has about 4,000 people/square km. NYC as a whole has 10,400. Manhattan has 26,800. The U.S. as a whole has 35. Not 35,000, just 35.

Comment: @reirab in Berlin in most areas parking is free, but spots are limited and traffic laws are strictly enforced. Public parking with meters in Germany can be anything from 20c to 1 EUR per 30 minutes and public garages usually top out at 12 or 15 EUR for 24h but are comparably cheap for shopping or restaurant visits. Also, I have never seen valet parking in Germany. We would never give our car to anyone. Maybe in high end five star hotels, but I have not seen it there either, and you wouldn't tip them anyway because of the non exitant tipping culture. I see the space problem point though.

Comment: @simbabque Good luck finding a restaurant in San Francisco where you can have a meal for less than $20, unless you order only one plate and drink tap water.

Comment: @phoog City's full of cheap eats, ask a local. **Locals have to eat somewhere**. Pluto's, Tú Lan, Buckhorn, any Mission burrito place, Original Buffalo Wings, Crepevine, Marcellos, etc.  We're not talking *table service* here (well we are at Chow or Orphan Andys). Many are "holes in the wall" or uptown because downtown rents.  And if you're in the suburbs, sky's the limit - Mama's Royal cafe, Barney's, Zachary's, Red Tractor, on and on and on.

Comment: Waiting for the street sweeper is hardly the only, or even most common, way to find street parking. That entire bullet point is bizarre and out of place to me (native New Yorker). Sure, it’s *a* way to get street parking, and I’m sure people do it regularly if the timing works out for them, but a lot more people have to park somewhere without happening to be there at the time the street cleaning actually happens. Also, on fire hydrants, if you just get a ticket you can consider yourself lucky. That’s a towing offense and towing is very common for it.

Answer (score 33):

In Theory... sure.

In practice...

Unless you have a fairly good understanding of New York's somewhat arcane Alternate Side Parking rules, the patience of a saint, and the willingness to walk all the way across town once you've found a spot - and then to move your car daily and do it all again because of the aforementioned ASP rules - you're not going to find this viable or pleasant.

Comment: It should also be noted that at certain times of year (summer weekends, thanksgiving weekend, winter holidays) many New Yorkers who have cars use them to leave the city, making it easier to find a spot, and street-cleaning rules are suspended, reducing the need to move the car around.

Comment: Sure. But ASP suspensions aren't quite as predictable or consistent as a blanket "holiday == free parking". That's where the 'fairly good understanding' part I mention comes in. The point is, it's not worth planning on unless you already know how the system works.

Comment: Can we convince you to teach us about this system? Sounds mighty interesting.

Comment: @Mast it's not. The system is "most of the time, you have to do what the sign says. On most holidays, and occasionally for emergencies and special events, you don't." TV and radio news make a point of saying "alternate side parking rules are suspended" on days when they are, and the info is also published on the web and twitter. It's not so much arcane as inconvenient, because Murphy's law dictates that you'll have to move your car at the least convenient possible time.

Comment: [an example of the no parking + broom symbol designating an ASP restriction](http://www.wnyc.org/i/raw/1/transportation201011alternate-side.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Another helpful tip, is look for spots in neighborhoods near your destination where street parking is usually more available, then you can hop on a nearby subway line to get to your destination. For example, if you want to go somewhere off the 2/3 or A/C or 4/5 or J/Z line, there is usually free parking between the South Street Seaport and the Brooklyn Bridge - and these spots are a short walk from all these subway lines at the Fulton Street Center (Fulton St. & Broadway). As stated above, just make sure you are not violating the alternate side parking rules on nearby signs, and that you are not blocking fire hydrants or driveways.

A couple other examples: on Riverside Drive from about 72nd Street on the Upper West Side all the way up to Washington Heights - this is a short walk to many 1 and 2/3 train stations. Bonus: there are hardly any driveways.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers correctly mention that the Alternate Side Parking rules are difficult and arcane, there is no longer the need to actually understand them as a tourist. Instead, you can use one of the online ASP maps to find streets which you can use for free parking at any given moment. For example SpotAngels has the [following handy map](https://www.spotangels.com/#id=2005272&address=205%20E%20Broadway%20New%20York):

[image]

It shows free street parking, paid street parking and parking garages, all in the same view. Most of the free spots will probably be busy by the time you arrive, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that NYC, Washington D.C. and other "large" meto areas in the New England area are generally considered "public transit friendly."

For example, last time I stayed in D.C. I parked my car at the hotel upon arival, and took combinations of the Subway, Train, Taxi, and Bus anywhere I wanted to go. I didn't drive at all that week.

IIRC NYC and srounding areas are very similar. You typically walk, or take public transit everywhere.

Your hotel should offer you some parking options, though, if your flying in, best to not even get a rental. Just take a taxi instead.

Comment: While your point is well taken, neither NYC nor D.C. is in "New England" by a long shot.

Comment: Didn't mean that they were, just that the same goes for them.